# Math Not Adding Up - UITableView Delete Row Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am getting an error when trying to delete a row from a `UITableView`:

Here is the data for my Table View:

```
var tmpArray = ["test"];
```

Here is how the TableView gets the number of rows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tmpArray.count;
}
```

Here is the body of the method I call to remove rows:

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic);
tmpArray.remove(at: 0);
```

Here is the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

The odd part is that there should be 1 row in the section before the row is deleted, not 2.

Any ideas as to why this error is occurring?

I have reviewed several posts, and although relevant, the solution provided here does not work:
[UITableView Deleteing row error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211033/uitableview-deleteing-row-error)

**Update**
When I call the remove commands separately, the error still persists:

```
tmpArray.remove(at: 0);
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic);
```

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Your update is no different. As I stated in my answer, you need to swap the two lines. Call `tmpArray.remove(at:0)` before you call `deleteRows`.

Comment: I made a mistake when I posted the update. I did reverse the lines in Xcode. Adding real code now.

Comment: Show more code. There's not enough context to what you have in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use this line in your code?

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic);
```

Can't it be like updating your data source and reloading UITableView? Like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        //1. remove data from model
        data.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        //2. reload TableView
        [tableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Or try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        //1. remove data from model
        data.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        //2. remove row from view
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)




    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to animate this?

Comment: Don't reload the whole table just to delete one row.

Comment: Yah, I don't think this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Below two lines should work, please maintain the order of call:

```
tmpArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic);
```

IMHO...calling reloadData() is a costlier call here but at the end of the show its your call.